# How to add supplemental documents in DocuSign?

Tags: php, docusignapi

I am trying to add supplemental/supporting documents in DocuSign that should appear in the recipient view request (embedded sign) whenever I am about to sign the docs. I don't understand why the docs are not showing there.

I am not receiving any error or any such. The process works fine as it creates the envelope and User are able to request a recipient view. The only thing that is missing are the supplemental documents.

```
// for testing we directly upload the file and convert to base64
$content_bytes = file_get_contents('../app/Support/DocuSign/sample.pdf');
$doc2_b64 = base64_encode($content_bytes);

# Create the document models
$document2 = new Document([  # create the DocuSign document object
    'document_base64' => $doc2_b64,
    'name' => 'sample',  # can be different from actual file name
    'file_extension' => 'pdf',  # many different document types are accepted
    'document_id' => '2',  # a label used to reference the doc
    'display' => 'modal',
    'signer_must_acknowledge' => 'view',
]);

$clientSigner = $instance->createClientSigner($data);
$consultantSigner = $instance->createConsultantSigner();

// Recipients object:
$recipientsServerTemplate = new Recipients([
    'signers' => [$clientSigner, $consultantSigner],
]);

// Create a composite template for the Server template + roles
$compTemplate = new CompositeTemplate([
    'composite_template_id' => '1',
    // Add supporting documents
    // 'document' => $doc1,
    'server_templates' => [
        new ServerTemplate([
            'sequence' => '1',
            'template_id' => $instance->docuSignTemplate->template_id,
        ]),
    ],
    // Add the roles via an inlineTemplate
    'inline_templates' => [
        new InlineTemplate([
            'sequence' => '2',
            'recipients' => $recipientsServerTemplate,
        ]),
    ],
]);

$envelopeDefinition = new EnvelopeDefinition();

$envelopeDefinition->setStatus('sent');
# The order in the docs array determines the order in the envelope
$envelopeDefinition->setDocuments([$document2]);
$envelopeDefinition->setCompositeTemplates([$compTemplate]);

return $envelopeDefinition;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a second **CompositTemplate** for your supplemental document.

```
    // Create a composite template for the supplemental document
    $compTemplate2 = new CompositeTemplate([
        'composite_template_id' => '2',
        // Add supporting documents
        'document' => $doc1
    ]);

    // copy your code for the original $compTemplate here

    $envelopeDefinition = new EnvelopeDefinition();
    $envelopeDefinition->setStatus('sent');
    # The order in the docs array determines the order in the envelope
    $envelopeDefinition->setCompositeTemplates([$compTemplate, $compTemplate2]);
```

See PHP code in GitHub - https://github.com/docusign/code-examples-php/blob/master/src/Services/Examples/eSignature/AddDocToTemplateService.php